# Delete in spring data jpa with multiple where clause

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to delete record from MySQL table.

Query  which i have written in the interface which extends JpaRepositoy is.

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value="DELETE FROM tablename WHERE end_date>=?1 and username=?2 and start_date <=?3)
void deleteByStart_dateAndUsernameAndEnd_date(Date start_date,String username,Date end_date);
```

**I want to pass start_date which is less than or equal to end_date and end_date is  greater than or equal to start_date** .

I am getting below exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [delete from com.poc.pa.model.tablename where end_date>=?1 and username=?2 and start_date <=?3]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [delete from com.poc.pa.model.tablename where end_date>=?1 and username=?2 and start_date <=?3]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to perform delete operation using above query.
I want to pass start_date which is less than or equal to end_date and end_date is greater than or equal to start_date .

Comment: I'm sorry, my comment was irrelevant,

Comment: Since its a DML statement,it seems it has an issue with write operation(as per the exception message). Can you please check if you have proper imports or not:
org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional and org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying.
You can also check if the credentials which you are mentioning to connect to database should have write grant on database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the delete statement is a SQL Query. Therefor you have to declare this in the Query annotation. Simply add **nativeQuery = true**

```
@Transactional    
@Modifying
@Query(value="DELETE FROM tablename WHERE end_date>=?1 and username=?2 and start_date <=?3, 
    nativeQuery = true)
void deleteByStart_dateAndUsernameAndEnd_date(Date start_date,String username,Date end_date);
```